# Otimizar modulo 10 SQL Server

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, query, otimização

Possuo um banco de dados criado a apróx. uma década, este mesmo banco possui diversos registros e obviamente, por estar em produção, não pode ser alterado do dia para noite.

O problema é:

> Os produtos cadastrados no banco possuem seriais, estes seriais no início de tudo não havia necessidade de gravar o dígito verificador, porém, hoje em dia o dígito é necessário para gerar relatórios e tudo mais.

Para calcular este dígito faz se modulo de 10 com os 19 números do serial, para realizar este calculo, temos uma função do *SQL server* que inicia um `while` para quebrar e somar os digitos do serial. Outro `while` para realizar os cálculos necessários e depois um `if`, para retornar o número equivalente em delta.

Abaixo a função:

```
DECLARE @delta AS TABLE ( indice INT, valor INT )

  INSERT  INTO @delta
          ( indice, valor )
  VALUES  ( 0, 0 ),
          ( 1, 1 ),
          ( 2, 2 ),
          ( 3, 3 ),
          ( 4, 4 ),
          ( 5, -4 ),
          ( 6, -3 ),
          ( 7, -2 ),
          ( 8, -1 ),
          ( 9, 0 )

DECLARE @serie VARCHAR(50) = '############'
DECLARE @deltaindex INT
DECLARE @deltavalue INT
DECLARE @soma INT = 0
DECLARE @i INT = 1

WHILE ( @i <= LEN(@serie) )
    BEGIN
        SET @soma = @soma + CAST(SUBSTRING(@serie, @i, 1) AS INT)
        SET @i = @i + 1
    END
SET @i = LEN(@serie)
WHILE ( @i > 0 )
    BEGIN
        SET @deltaindex = CAST(SUBSTRING(@serie, @i, 1) AS INT)
        SELECT  @deltavalue = valor
        FROM    @delta
        WHERE   indice = @deltaindex
        SET @soma = @soma + @deltavalue
        SET @i = @i - 2
    END
DECLARE @mod10 INT
SET @mod10 = @soma % 10
SET @mod10 = 10 - @mod10
IF ( @mod10 = 10 )
    BEGIN
        SET @mod10 = 0
    END
PRINT @mod10
```

Dito isso, temos aprox. 1,5KK de registros que necessitam ser exibidos em um relatório e cada registro possui entre 1 e 2 seriais e esta consulta por serial acaba atrasando bastante a exibição do relatório, o suficiente para que eu não consiga emitir um relatório pelo sistema muito menos pelo banco, demorando em torno de 1H30 para emitir e mesmo assim tive que cancelar a consulta.

Gostaria de saber se há alguma forma de otimizar o modulo de 10 para que a consulta não atrase tanto.

Comment: O serial tem sempre 19 algarismos?

Comment: Não, varia entre 5 e 49

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variáveis de tabela são armazenadas no disco, no banco de dados tempdb, assim como as tabelas temporárias. Então, pode ser que a baixa performance seja causada pelo uso da variável de tabela @delta para cálculos que podem ser implementados por uma expressão matemática. Outro fator é que funções do tipo escalar degradam a performance, por natureza. Funções são mais eficientes quando são do tipo *inline table-valued*.

Segue sugestão de otimização. A tabela @delta foi eliminada e substituída por um cálculo matemático bem simples. Avalie a performance e a correção da sugestão, pois não tive como testar. Se houver algum erro no código, nos avise para que possamos corrigir.

```
-- código #1 v3
declare @serie varchar(50) = '1234567890123456789';
declare @deltaindex int, @deltavalue int, @soma int, @i int, @tamserie int;
set @tamserie = len(@serie);

set @i = 1;
set @soma = 0;
while ( @i <= @tamserie )
    begin
    set @soma = @soma + cast(substring(@serie, @i, 1) as int);
    set @i = @i + 1;
    end;

set @i = @tamserie;
while ( @i > 0 )
    begin
    set @deltaindex = cast(substring(@serie, @i, 1) as int);
    set @deltavalue= case when (@deltaindex <= 4) then @deltaindex
                          else ((9 - @deltaindex) * -1) end;
    set @soma = @soma + @deltavalue;
    set @i = @i - 2;
    end;

declare @mod10 int;
set @mod10 = 10 - (@soma % 10);
IF ( @mod10 = 10 )
    set @mod10 = 0;

PRINT @mod10;
```

Comment: Olá josé, iriei testar a performance do mesmo, porém, o serial pode variar de 5 a 49 caracteres.

Comment: @MárcioEric Alterei o código para aceitar até 50 algarismos no número de série.